# Start Terminal from QtCreator

Tags: terminal, qt-creator

I want to start a Terminal in Windows (cmd.exe) or Linux (/bin/bash) out of QtCreator (2.8.1). The Terminal should have the same environment, QtCreator uses to start compiled projects. I have not found such an option.

I only need the plain terminal, I don't want to start the project in terminal mode!